# My docker run crash during the test phase of my gitlab CI

Tags: java, docker, gitlab, continuous-integration

So i am quite new to the whole CI topic and im trying to run tests after my merge request in my pipeline. Except that when my command try to run the container i have an error.
So this is my gitlab-ci file

```yaml
image: docker:18

variables:
  REPO_URL: "registry.gitlab.com/xxxxx/xxxxxxx"
  PROD_SRV: "xxx"
  DEV_SRV: "xxx"

services:
  - docker:dind

stages:
  - build jar
  - build docker image
  - tests
  

maven-build:
  only:
    - work
    - test
  image: maven:3-jdk-8
  stage: build jar
  script: "mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true package -B"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - target/*.jar
    expire_in: 7 days

docker build:
  stage: build docker image
  only:
    - work
    - test
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login --username "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"  "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
    - chmod a+x ./mvnw
  script:
    - docker info
    - docker build -t $REPO_URL:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker images
    - docker push $REPO_URL:$CI_COMMIT_SHA

  after_script:
    - docker logout registry.gitlab.com 2>/dev/null
    - rm /root/.docker/config.json 2>/dev/null


tests job branch test:
  stage: tests
  only:
    - test
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  before_script:
    - echo "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" | docker login --username "$CI_REGISTRY_USER"  "$CI_REGISTRY" --password-stdin
  script:
    - docker pull $REPO_URL:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker run -t $REPO_URL:$CI_COMMIT_SHA .
    - docker push $REPO_URL:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  after_script:
    - docker logout registry.gitlab.com 2>/dev/null
    - rm /root/.docker/config.json 2>/dev/null
```

and this is my dockerfile

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

FROM openjdk:16-alpine3.13 as base

WORKDIR /amsn-counter

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./
RUN ./mvnw dependency:go-offline
COPY src ./src

FROM base as test
RUN ["./mvnw", "test"]

FROM base as development
CMD ["./mvnw", "spring-boot:run", "-Dspring-boot.run.profiles=mysql", "-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000'"]

FROM base as build
RUN  ./mvnw package

FROM openjdk:11-jre-slim as production
EXPOSE 8080

ADD /target/linkedin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

and the error in the pipeline as well:
[image: and the error in the pipeline as well]

If you need any precision i will gladly answer, and like i said im new so don't hesitate to point if something is weird in the files or in my description in general

Edit: My branch are named {work}(local branch) and {test}

Comment: The error appears to be a Java programming error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: add your main class`. Have you tried running your dockerfile locally?

Comment: It run just fine locally i don't know why but the container created in the CI seems to be empty.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if there is no target specified when you are running `docker build`. Try this:

```
script:
  - docker info
  - image_name="$REPO_URL:$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
  - docker build
      --target test
      --tag $image_name
      .
  - docker push $image_name
```